# Is it possible to create a VsCode extension using flutter

Tags: flutter, vscode-extensions

I'm practising flutter for years. I recently found that we can create chrome extensions using flutter but is there any way to create VScode extensions in flutter?

Comment: You can even create Windows extensions in C/C++ but still VS Code only supports TypeScript/JavaScript based extensions. "we can create chrome extensions using flutter" is totally irrelevant.

Comment: No, But you may try embedding a web-app from flutter inside the environment but you cannot yet communicate with underlying vs-code apis using it,

Comment: that's interesting

Comment: @KrishBhanushali how do python based extensions do that? e.g https://vscode-ext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating-your-extension/